# Not able to send messages to kafka topic through java code

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka. This is my code , where i want to send messages to kafka server,Topic name is "west" with message "message1".I'm not getting any error though i haven't seen my sent messages in the topic is there anything wrong here?

```java
class SimpleProducer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{       
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers","172.xxxxxxxxx:9092");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder");
    props.put("acks", "1");
    props.put("retries", 1);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 0);
    props.put("client.id", "foo");
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("timeout.ms", "500");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "500"); 
    props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "100");

    System.out.println("ready to send msg");

    try {
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("west","message1"));

        System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
        producer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Messgae doesn't sent successfully");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking for messages written and committed to the broker?

Comment: As of now i'm sending the message to some particular topic and checking it with the below command :-

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic-name --from-beginning

Comment: I'm writing a custom producer to get my messages from Java to the topic.
Calling the shown main does not result into a message on the Kafka topic nor does it print any error message.

Does anybody have an idea why the message does not arrive in my topic?

Answer (score 0):

The API you used to send the message is asynchronous.  Use the form of send() which has two arguments.  The second argument is a Callback which you can use to see if the send really worked or if there was an error somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
   producer.send(yourRecord,
                 new Callback() {
                     public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                         if(e != null) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                         } else {
                            System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                         }
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: Please do not provide an answer that is only code. Explain how this code should be used and why it solves the problem.